# How to apply paging to a dataset?

Tags: asp.net, .net, pagination, dataset

How can I apply paging to a dataset? I have a method in which I dynamically build a table from a dataset. Querying the database from which I get my dataset from is not an issue but iterating the datarows from the dataset is slow.

To increase performance when loading a page containing a lot of datarows I want to apply paging ability.

A feature that would be good to have is ability for the user to set pagesize (how many rows to display on each page).

Comment: You may either want to look at the DataPager control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager.aspx or paging via stored procedure.  You can even maintain a page, start index, and page size on your page itself and fill your dataset with a subset of data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your data is a single DataTable then you can use the AsEnumerable() extension method.  That will return the data as an IEnumerable collection.  You can then use the LINQ extension methods .Skip() and .Take().

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> MyDataPage = MyDataTable.AsEnumerable().Skip(100).Take(10);
```

The above code would give you rows 101 to 110 of MyDataTable and it would be an IEnumerable collection which you can bind just like a data table.  If you need it to be an actual DataTable you can just call CopyToDataTable() thus:

```
DataTable NewDT = MyDataPage.CopyToDataTable();
```

More detailed info is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a GridView to show the data and use its paging ability:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5aw1xfh3%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yes but on my company we don't use webcontrols such as gridview, listview, dataview, .... , .... We usally build up tables manually and dynamically in the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

Linq is best option.

ROW_NUMBER() is also an option in SQL server 2005

Comment: Is this also possible in SQL server 2008?